# SSH, disable logging for a certain user

Tags: linux, ssh, logging

I want to have a user connecting via SSH every certain time and I want to remove the logging left by that user in the SSH logs to avoid disk usage and to hide this user activity.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To remove specific entries in the logs? That'd be very difficult with SSH itself.  I would recommend either creating a root Cron job or set a login/logout script (if bash, in the .bash_logout & .bash_profile files) that removes the entries of that user logging in and logging out/their .bash_history.

Other than that you would need some sort of directive in (Maybe?) a 3rd party logging daemon that removes those logs. But there will still be entries of their login (I.e., the last command, files moved/changed by their user or even added, /var/log/secure, other rc/history files, tmp files generated by tasks, etc etc)